# jquery post request not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I have searched and tried all the possible ways in here but it didn't fix my problem. then I decided to ask the question.
I have a HTML/PHP page that has list of teams and there is a button to update the team name. I am trying to edit the team name without refreshing the page.
here is my HTML/PHP:

```
<input id="team_name_input_field_<?php echo $teamID; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $team_name; ?>" style="display:none;">
<input id="team_name_update_button_<?php echo $teamID; ?>" type="button" value="Update" style="display:none;" onClick="updateTeamName(<?php echo $teamID; ?>);">
```

so onclick of the update button, I am sending the $teamID to my jquery function. here is my jquery:

```
function updateTeamName(moo)
{
    var name = $("#team_name_input_field_" + moo).val();

    if($.trim(name) != '' && $.trim(name) != 'N/A')
    {
        $.post('add_team_name.php', {name: name}, function(data){
            alert(data);//this is not working 
        });
        alert(moo);//this is working
    }

    else
    {
        alert("enter something please");
    }
}
```

So moo is the teamID and I am taking the team_name as well and storing it in the name variable. and there is add_team_name.php that is responsible to add the name. but I want to first test if I can get data from add_team_name.php. here is add_team_name.php:

```
<?PHP

echo "hahahahaha";

?>
```

I am just echoing "hahahaha" in add_team_name.php and I am alerting the data in the jquery. but nothing is getting alerted. Then I added another alert(moo); after the jquery post and that is alerting moo. so the problem is with my post I think. because I have to be able to get the "hahahahaha" when I alert data.
Thanks in advance.

note: my php/html page is in the main directory and the jquery file and add_team_name.php are in the js folder.

Comment: First remove this space `{name: name}` -> `{name:name}`

Comment: How nothing alerted? If you `alert("testo");` in your post callback, does it appear?

Comment: when you say this is not working. you mean that the alert is not show up or it's show up but without the text `hahahaha`?

Comment: @Circle73: I have done it and it is the same

Comment: Which version of jquery library are you using?

Comment: @sergeSeredenko: any alert inside the post callback is not appearing.

Comment: @Dvir: The alert is not showing at all

Comment: @NabeelSheikh: I'm using jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Try adding this to your php file `$name = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: change `<?PHP` to `<?php`.

Comment: @AminRaeisi Are you sure you didn't misspell the name of the file / it is in the same directory as the page with the form? You could use Firebug in Mozilla of Dev Tools in Chrome to track your ajax request. It seems some error occurs.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko: This is something I dont understand. I tried Chrome Console and I found that the I have to add js/ before the add_team_name.php in the post callback. so that fixed the problem. but why? my js file that has the callback and the php page that echos the message "hahaha" are in the same directory.

Comment: The post request's URL is relative to the document's URL, not relative to the JavaScript file's URL. It's usually good practice to use absolute URLs in your AJAX requests, for example in this case `/js/add_team_name.php`

Comment: @OivaEskola: Thanks. :) so how I choose the answer now? it is all in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is with file locations. Php script was put in `/js/` directory with a .js file from which request was made, instead of root where was the html/php page including that .js

Comment: Thanks Serge Seredenko!
Just wanted to mention the point that @OivaEskola said:
"The post request's URL is relative to the document's URL, not relative to the JavaScript file's URL. It's usually good practice to use absolute URLs in your AJAX requests, for example in this case /js/add_team_name.php"

Comment: @AminRaeisi 'Usually' is a good word. If you don't rewrite your urls to one single index.php in the root, and really use a lot of pages in directories, relative requests could be quite convenient. Just an example. But 'usually' — yeah.